# What is the best way to export env variable within Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook, recipe

I am trying to set env variable within Chef recipe so that after the recipe is run, I can do `echo $VAR1`

```
  bash 'set_env_var' do
    code <<-EOH
      echo export VAR1="https://#{node['fqdn']}" >> /etc/profile
      source /etc/profile
    EOH
    not_if "grep -q VAR1="https://#{node['fqdn']}" >> /etc/profile"
  end
```

Please let me know if there is a better way to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature that Unix supports. The closest you can get is writing to something like `/etc/profile.d` if your distro's default shell RC files support it but that both won't have any effect on the current shell (you would need to start a new one) and doesn't cover all execution scenarios. Environment variables are probably the wrong answer to whatever you are trying to solve.

Comment: should I consider adding value of `VAR1` in a file and then reading out the `VAR1` value from the file.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing, but yes, a configuration file would be more standard.